# navigate inside http module nativescript

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, nativescript, synchronous

Please help me to solve this problem
i want to navigate to another frame after http module finish its request. Code below :

```
var datanya = 'token='+konfigurasi.tokenapps+'&email='+inputan['email']+'&nama='+inputan['nama']+'&handphone='+inputan['handphone']+'&alamat='+inputan['alamat']+'&longitude='+longi+'&latitude='+lat              +'&model='+cekPlatform.device.model+'&tipe='+cekPlatform.device.deviceType+'&manufaktur='+cekPlatform.device.manufacturer
+'&region='+cekPlatform.device.region;
httpModul.request({
                    url:  'http://example.com/c_user/daftar/',
                    method: "POST",
                    timeout: 10000,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                    content: datanya

                 }).then(function(response){
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    //console.log(response);

                    console.log('data diterima : '+response.content);
                    var jsondata = response.content.toJSON();
                    console.log('JSON Data hasil '+JSON.stringify(response.content));
                    loader.hide();
                    if(jsondata.hasil=='error'){
                        console.log('error '+jsondata.alasan);
                        Toast.makeText(jsondata.alasan, "long").show();
                    }else{
                        console.log('success : '+jsondata.alasan);
                        Toast.makeText(jsondata.alasan, "long").show();

                        //navigate
                        fm.topmost().navigate("otp/cek_daftar");
                        console.log('navigation passed');

                    }
                 },function(err){
                    //return error;
                    Toast.makeText('Error : '+err, "long").show();
                    console.log(err);
                 })
```

But it wont work with navigation. From searching i got information http module use asynchronous maybe it wont work with navigation that used synchronous.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate fine in the download promise handler; I do so in one of my projects; download the orders then navigate to the orders screen.   However, a couple things it could be:

1. Does  fm = `require ('ui/frame');`
2. In your navigate have you tried `.navigate('~/otp/cek_daftar');`
3. Have you tried putting a Try/Catch around the navigate to see why that page isn't navigating too, you might have a bug in that page and so it is failing...
4. Are you getting the console:  `console.log('data diterima : '+response.content);`